# In Oracle How do we get multiple columns in result which are not in tables

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, oracle19c

For example :

I have below table named **"T1"**

[image]

and I need result like this:

[image]

if **"earlist_run_date"** , **"last_rundate**" & **"remainng_run_dates"** where in the table **T1** could have used **PIVOT**.

But i don't know how to bring these 3 columns in result set. Any Solution will be much appreciated

Comment: What does it mean "remaining_run_dates"? In your table, those dates are not "remaining". Whats the purpose of those dates? I couldn't even imagin why this information (which is the more complex of your query) is required.

Comment: remaining_run_dates are the dates in between first run and last run of specific job_id. I got this question form interview.

Comment: Yes yes... I understand... But why are they needed? Can't you just deduce them from the earlist/last fields? If there are 2 years between earliest and last dates you want in that column 730 dates?

Comment: @jaime-drq  You are right i dint think that one , But even if i can remove  "remaining_run_dates" how will i bring other two columns in result

Comment: The query is quite simplier if you remove that column, I show you in the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like this.  There's probably a better way to eliminate the first and last row from the `listagg` that I'm not seeing off the top of my head but this should be reasonably efficient.

```
with ranked_t1 as (
  select t1.*,
         rank() over( partition by job_id
                          order by run_date asc ) asc_rank,
         rank() over( partition by job_id
                          order by run_date desc ) desc_rank
    from t1
)
select job_id,
       min( run_date ) earliest_run_date,
       max( run_date ) last_rundate,
       listagg( (case when asc_rank != 1
                       and desc_rank != 1
                      then run_date
                      else null
                   end), ' ' )
         within group( order by run_date ) remaining_run_dates
  from ranked_t1
 group by job_id;
```

Comment: I hope you can support him when he has jobs running for more than a year. It's good to have far of my job the people who upvoted this answer...

Comment: @JaimeDrq - Sure, if you want the report to concatenate a thousand dates together, you'd need to use a user-defined aggregate returning a `clob` rather than `listagg`.  If a `job_id` can have the same `run_date` twice, you'd need to discuss requirements and whether to use `row_number` or `dense_rank` rather than `rank`.  And it's certainly reasonable to ask the business user why they want something like this and whether there is a better way to get them the information they're after.

Comment: Thank you @JustinCave, at least it makes me feel good that there is someone who thinks

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `remaining_run_dates` column, you get a query as simple as

```
select 
  JOB_ID, 
  min(RUN_DATE) as earliest_run_date,
  max(RUN_DATE) as last_rundate
from T1
group by JOB_ID
```

Comment: Yeah but `remaining_run_dates` is a specified requirement, so we can't just drop it.

Comment: The question clearly states *"I need result like this"* and shows an image of a report with list of remaining run dates. It's your business whether you think this requirement is absurd, but it's not unusual for reports to include concatenated strings of values (that's why Oracle has given us the `listagg()` function). As for who I am, you can click on my profile if you're really that interested.

Comment: If you want to know, I tell you. `listagg()`  has a maximum size of 4000 characters. So, if we understand a date in its minimum expressión (yyyymmdd), we have room for 500 dates. Are you still thinking that this is a good solution?

Comment: Since Oracle 12.2 `listagg()` as supported the ON OVERFLOW clause to handle that situation. Prior to that yes we had to explicitly apply a `substr()` to handle potential overflows. Beyond that, I tend to find users resent having their requirements dismissed as "stupid".  I think it's more fruitful to discuss limitations and workarounds, and establish what we can implement to satisfy their need. But if your approach works for you then fine.

Comment: @APC now we start to understand us... Sorry if I was rude, but it makes me quite mad to do things just because "they told me". I think that one of the strong points of the IT person is to guide the user on what he/she wants. In this case, for me, having a column with tons of dates, is useless, and likely there is a better way to solve the problem.